# how to call with inherited class in parent class

Tags: inheritance, without-sharing

below is the code what i am trying is to fetch contact record in without sharing mode.

commented part has the problem and it showing

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   InheritedSharingClass() from the type
>   ParentClass.InheritedSharingClass

```
 public without sharing class ParentClass{

 public inherited sharing class InheritedSharingClass {
    public List<Contact> getAllTheSecrets(){
        return [SELECT name,owner.name FROM Contact];
    }
 }

public ParentClass(){
   // ParentClass.InheritedSharingClass childcls = new ParentClass.InheritedSharingClass();
      //  childcls.InheritedSharingClass();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `InheritedSharingClass` does not exist in your class, probably you are trying to access `getAllTheSecrets` so your code will be like

```
public without sharing class ParentClass{

 public inherited sharing class InheritedSharingClass {
    public List<Contact> getAllTheSecrets(){
        return [SELECT name,owner.name FROM Contact];
    }
 }

public ParentClass(){
    ParentClass.InheritedSharingClass childcls = new ParentClass.InheritedSharingClass();
        childcls.getAllTheSecrets();
      }
 }
```

Comment: what are you trying to show in VF?

Comment: as you already have function i.e. getAllTheSecrets, you can access contacts like `<apex:repeat value="{!AllTheSecrets}" var="secrete" id="theRepeat">`, you may also use `pageblocktable`